# 'URL No Longer Exists' when creating Voice Call record using Salesforce Telephony Integration API

Tags: rest, jwt, salesforce, telephony, salesforce-einstein

I am working to integrate my company's telephony system with Salesforce so we can use Einstein Conversation Insights on our call recordings. I've created a JWT and can properly authorize, but when I try to [create a test Voice Call](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.voice_developer_guide.meta/voice_developer_guide/voice_rest_voicecalls_create.htm), I get the following 404 Response:

```
    <table cellspacing=10>
    <tr>
        <td><span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 12pt;">URL No Longer Exists</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>You have attempted to reach a URL that no longer exists on salesforce.com. <br/><br/>

You may have reached this page after clicking on a direct link into the application. This direct link might be: <br/>
&#8226; A bookmark to a particular page, such as a report or view <br/>
&#8226; A link to a particular page in the Custom Links section of your Home Tab, or a Custom Link <br/>
&#8226; A link to a particular page in your email templates <br/><br/>
If you reached this page through a bookmark, you are probably trying to access something that has moved. Please update your bookmark.
            <br/>
            <br/>If you reached this page through any of the other direct links listed above, please notify your administrator to update the link.
            <br/><br/>If you reached this page through a link on our site, please <a href="/cases/logabug.jsp">report
                the broken link directly to our Support Team</a> and we will fix it promptly. Please indicate the page
            you were on when you clicked the link as well as any other related information. We apologize for the
            inconvenience.
            <br/><br/>Thank you again for your patience and assistance. And thanks for using salesforce.com!</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The endpoint/URL I've been using in my POST request is 
https://myCompany.my.salesforce.com/services/telephony/v1/voiceCalls

I've successfully queried other endpoints, so I don't think the issue lies within my JWT or authorization. I have "Enable clickjack protection for customer Visualforce pages with standard headers" disable as I've seen some other troubleshooting sites suggest. I've tried different variations of the endpoint and of our URL, but no luck with anything.

Answer (score 0):

Telephony api uses the conversation and routing services, try out this endpoint:https://mycompany.my.salesforce-scrt.com/services/telephony/v1/voiceCalls.

Btw, how did you do generate the jwt?